# JQuery hide/show content of multiple divs on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to show/hide multiple divs at the same time. I'm using `anchor` tag to achieve this. I want to change content of two separate divs at same time. One div holds iframe and other video description.
So far I've managed to make one of my divs change it's content, but not the other. Is there a way to make content of both divs change when I click on `anchor` tag ?

My code. HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2 class='text-center'>Left Side</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a class='myTag' href="#" rel="one">One</a></li>
        <li><a class='myTag' href="#" rel="two">Two</a></li>
        <li><a class='myTag' href="#" rel="three">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2 class='text-center'>Right Side</h2>
      <div id='zero'>
        <img src="https://img.clipartfest.com/d28d6e716da993963c5b8b871f944141_the-golden-goose-01-golden-goose-clipart_295-230.jpeg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div id='one' style="display: none">
        <iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/89_KXT5ztTU">
        </iframe>
      </div>
      <div id='two' style="display: none">
        <iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XlvZdsO5sIg">
        </iframe>
      </div>
      <div id='three' style="display: none">
        <iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uVoc4AzBX70">
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <h2>Lower container</h2>
      <div id='zero'>
        <p>This text needs to change. Video description</p>
      </div>
      <div id='one' style="display: none">
        <p>This is my video description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.myTag').on('click', function(){
  var target = $(this).attr('rel');
  $("#"+target).show('slow').siblings("div").hide('slow');
});
```

Also a followup question can I make this toggleable (I've tried adding toggle() at the end of my line, but it just made everything worse), so when I click on `anchor` tag again it returns original image ?
Here is the codepen so you can better understand my problem : https://codepen.io/Karadjordje/pen/ybRyyo?editors=1010

Comment: where do you get the video description?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crux of your problem is that IDs must be unique. If you have multiple of the same ID then it will never work as expected. I switched things to classes and it's working as you expected.

```js
$('.myTag').on('click', function(){
  var target = $(this).attr('rel');
  $("."+target).show('slow').siblings("div").hide('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2 class='text-center'>Left Side</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a class='myTag' href="#" rel="one">One</a></li>
        <li><a class='myTag' href="#" rel="two">Two</a></li>
        <li><a class='myTag' href="#" rel="three">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2 class='text-center'>Right Side</h2>
      <div class='zero'>
        <img src="https://img.clipartfest.com/d28d6e716da993963c5b8b871f944141_the-golden-goose-01-golden-goose-clipart_295-230.jpeg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class='one' style="display: none">
        <iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/89_KXT5ztTU">
        </iframe>
      </div>
      <div class='two' style="display: none">
        <iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XlvZdsO5sIg">
        </iframe>
      </div>
      <div class='three' style="display: none">
        <iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uVoc4AzBX70">
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <h2>Lower container</h2>
      <div class='zero'>
        <p>This text needs to change. Video description</p>
      </div>
      <div class='one' style="display: none">
        <p>This is my video description</p>
      </div>
      <div class='two' style="display: none">
        <p>Two!</p>
      </div>
      <div class='three' style="display: none">
        <p>Three!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. So much time lost. Never would have guessed that solution was this simple .....

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having multiple divs for each description, use one div and change the content based on `rel` value. store the description inside an object and use `rel` value to get the description.

```js
// store your description in here
// on click the anchor tag get the rel value and display description
// like desc[relvalue]
var desc = {'one': 'no man no cry jimmy sax', 'two': 'Pendulum - hold on', 'three': 'Paul Van Dyk'};

$('.myTag').on('click', function(){
  var target = $(this).attr('rel');
  $("#"+target).show('slow').siblings("div").hide('slow');
  $('#desc p').html(desc[$(this).attr('rel')])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2 class='text-center'>Left Side</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a class='myTag' href="#" rel="one">One</a></li>
        <li><a class='myTag' href="#" rel="two">Two</a></li>
        <li><a class='myTag' href="#" rel="three">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2 class='text-center'>Right Side</h2>
      <div id='zero'>
        <img src="https://img.clipartfest.com/d28d6e716da993963c5b8b871f944141_the-golden-goose-01-golden-goose-clipart_295-230.jpeg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div id='one' style="display: none">
        <iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/89_KXT5ztTU">
        </iframe>
      </div>
      <div id='two' style="display: none">
        <iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XlvZdsO5sIg">
        </iframe>
      </div>
      <div id='three' style="display: none">
        <iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uVoc4AzBX70">
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <h2>Lower container</h2>
      <div id='desc'>
        <p>This text needs to change. Video description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Thank you for your answer. Do you think it's better then my original idea, lets say more efficient ?

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 I'm glad I could help

Comment: you can change the `zero` in the description to `desc`

Answer (score 0):

Change id to class...
Instead of id="one" put class="one", and in the jquery put:

```js
$('.myTag').on('click', function(){
  var target = $(this).attr('rel');
  $("."+target).show('slow').siblings("div").hide('slow');
});
```